# angular2 http request and websocket

Tags: angular, websocket, observable

Hi all I've an application that until now was only doing http request to retrieve data...now the problem is that we have also a websocket but I've no idea how to combine both of them:

This is my http request:

```
 public stock(): Observable<any> {
    if (!this._stock) {
        // rest api
        this._stock = this.http.get(url)
            .map((stock: Response) => {
                // cache the value
                stock.json().items.forEach((item) => {
                    this._stock[item.productKey] = item;
                });
                return this._stock;
            })
            .publishReplay(1)
            .refCount();
    }
    return this._stock;
}
```

This is the websocket:

```
public getStockMessages(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(obs => this.inventoryChannel.on(`STOCK`, (data) => {
        return obs.next(data);
    }));
}
```

Comment: it looks like the AJAX request is filtered down to a specific stock, and the web socket is not. It's not really apparent what you want the outcome of combining these two streams to be, or what you mean by combine. I'd like to help, but I can't given the question you've asked.

Comment: well the problem is that in the angular component you subscribe to a something: this.service.getStock((res)=> {...}) but if the websocket receive new informations (getStockMessages) because the stock is changed I need to put this information in the service getStock otherwise each component need to subscribe to 2 differents service to receive the first time the values and the other times the update.

Comment: So the there's an ajax request that gets one value, but after that you're getting additional values from the web socket?

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've said above, it seems like you're looking to:

1. Request a single value from the server.
2. Get additional values from a web socket.

```javascript
stock().concat(getStockMessages())
```

... is probably what you want.

But honestly I'm still having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're trying to do... but I *think* this will solve your problem.